# How to format a JSON snippet in a non-JSON file using jq?

Tags: key-bindings, formatting

I've got, in this case, a Perl module which has some `JSON` snippets inside of it. I'd like to be able to select the embedded `JSON` and format it via `jq`.  So far I've got:

`:vnoremap jq <esc>:'<,'>:w !jq<CR>`

That allows me to select some text, type `jq` and then the formatted text is displayed to me. However, it's not replacing the selected text. Nothing actually changes in my buffer. What am I missing here? I've seen lots of answers for how to format an entire file, but I can't find a workable answer for this particular use case.

Comment: Check `:h 'formatprg'`

Comment: `What am I missing here?` Remove `w`. (In fact, just `:!jq<CR>` is enough, the rest is a garbage).

Comment: @Matt if I run that command I just get `jq`'s help menu inserted into my file.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about `formatprg`. That's very handy. If I try `:set formatprg=jq` and then select the text and enter `gq`, the JSON is replaced with the help text from `jq`. I guess it's an issue with how `jq` is being invoked.

Comment: `vnoremap jq :!jq<cr>` works for me.

Comment: @Ralf thanks. I've got it now. I tried your suggestion and it did not work with `jq` version `jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe`. I upgraded to 1.6. It looks like this did the trick: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/commit/5fe053671a768d28bc9773719cc4a9a35e72f30d. I can get it to work with the older version by adding the ".": `vnoremap jq :!jq .<cr>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There at least two possible answers here:

```
vnoremap jq :!jq<cr>
```

as suggested by @Ralf works for `jq` >= 1.6. See https://github.com/stedolan/jq/commit/5fe053671a768d28bc9773719cc4a9a35e72f30d

For earlier `jq` versions where the dot is not implied, it needs to be in the command:

```
vnoremap jq :!jq .<cr>
```

I was using an older version of `jq`. The answer which adds the dot will work with both versions.

If you'd like your keys to be sorted:

```
vnoremap jq :!jq -S .<cr>
```

Comment: The formatprg version would be `set formatprg=jq\ .` or `let &formatprg = 'jq .'`

Answer (score -1):

This command will format and sort the json file

```
:%!jq -S .
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Note that this doesn't answer the question: OP wants to format snippets of JSON inside a file containing also other code. With `%` you are sending all the lines to `jq` so this is likely to insert an error message in your buffer since `jq` doesn't handle text which is not json.